# Last Modified of Folders

Tags: windows, filesystems

How does Windows determine the last modified date of a folder?

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this question? Is one of the given answers correct?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [MSDN](http://web.archive.org/web/20110705024711/http://support.microsoft.com/kb/299648), the last modification timestamp is stored per directory:

> - If you create two new folders on an NTFS partition called D:\NTFS1 and D:\NTFS2, both the created and modified date and time are the same.
> - If you move the D:\NTFS2 folder into the D:\NTFS1 folder, creating D:\NTFS1\NTFS2, then:
>
>   1. D:\NTFS1 - The created folder is the same and the modified stamp changes.
>   2. D:\NTFS1\NTFS2 - Both the created folder changes and the modified folder stay the same.
>        This behavior occurs because, even though you moved the folder, a new folder is seen as being created within the D:\NTFS1 folder by the Master File Table (MFT).
> - If you copy the D:\NTFS2 folder into the D:\NTFS1 folder, creating the D:\NTFS1\NTFS2 folder, and the D:\NTFS2 folder still exists (after having copied it):
>
>   1. D:\NTFS1 - The created folder is the same and the modified folder time and date stamp changes.
>   2. D:\NTFS2 - No changes occur because it is the original folder.
>   3. D:\NTFS1\NTFS2 - Both the created folder and the modified folder changes to the same stamp, which is that of the time of the move.
>        This behavior occurs because even though you copied the folder, the new folder is seen as being created by the MFT and is given a new created and modified time stamp.
>
> **Note**: The design and behavior of the FAT file system is different with regards to the modified time stamp. On a FAT file system, the modified date of a folder does not change if the contents of the folder change. For example, if you have D:\FAT1 and D:\FAT2, and you copy or move D:\FAT2 into D:\FAT1, the created date and modified date of D:\FAT1 remains the same.

Comment: As link above towards MSDN is not working, here is the archived copy from Wayback machine of that page from the time of posting of the answer.

https://web.archive.org/web/20110604022236/http://support.microsoft.com/kb/299648

Answer (score 2):

uses the date of last file activity inside the folder.

Comment: The answer is bull's eye

Answer (score 2):

When a directory entry is updated, the last modified date of the directory itself is also updated.

Comment: It appears to update went a directory entry is created or destroyed.