# How to monitor a directory in windows in time from the program exits to it restarts?

Tags: c++, windows, monitor

I wrote a music player for windows system.
And I add a module to monitor a directory called "Media library".
It can now read the changes of music file in that directory(adding, deleting, changing name..) while player is running.
It displays as a "auto playlist" , and those file's info it saved to a configure file,when the program exits.

It works fine now, but it has a flaw.

I can't get the changes when the program it not running.
And it's not a good idea to rescan the media library's directory again, it may contain large of file items.

So is there another way to do this?
By the way,it's placed in [my github](https://github.com/liaogang/player).

Comment: Everything is already added in the file system. You can get the date of last file activity inside the folder to increase speed of rescan the media library. Also, read it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/153803/last-modified-of-folders

Comment: Hi,llya,Can you tell me how to get the date of last file activity? and how to increase speed of rescan? I still can't understand.Thank you.

Comment: I've added my answer with explanation lower.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All modern file systems allows you to get information about date and time of last modification of file (for directories it means, that we can get date and time of previous modification of content of the directory). So, you can significantly increase speed of rescan operation using this information.

The idea is simple: while rescan you can ignore directory and all it's subdirectories if it was not changed since previous rescan. To get information about last modification of directory you can use function [GetFileTime()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/desktop/ms724320(v=vs.85)).

The idea of second process which uses `FindFirstChangeNotification()` and `ReadDirectoryChanges()` functions and which starts at the logon (idea of Ben Key) is good too. But I suspect that you already have implemented rescan function, so it sounds like good idea to increase it's speed. So I recommend you to try to use `GetFileTime()` for optimization of rescan.

Comment: What if i paste some files cut from other directory to the 'media library directory' , should i also need to rescan the whole directory again?

Comment: @liaogang, yes, because rescan is the only way to get information about modifications in folders (when you program wasn't run while these changes). But in this approach rescan will be very fast.

Comment: @liaogang, why do you focus on cut/paste operation? After any file modification in the directory, date of last file activity will be updated, so you easyly can catch it.

Comment: Thank you @llya , it helps me a lot.  scanning the file's id3v2 info takes many time.  I do believe the foobar2000 player have a better way to do this. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The following two functions may be of use.

**[FindFirstChangeNotification function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364417%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)**

Creates a change notification handle and sets up initial change notification filter conditions. A wait on a notification handle succeeds when a change matching the filter conditions occurs in the specified directory or subtree. The function does not report changes to the specified directory itself.

**[ReadDirectoryChangesW function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365465%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)**

Retrieves information that describes the changes within the specified directory. The function does not report changes to the specified directory itself.

Comment: Thanks. I am using ReadDirectoryChangesW. I need to read the file changes when the program is exits till it restarts .

Comment: My suggestion is a separate program that is always running, one that starts on log in.